# Searching vector values in BST

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

My node structure:

```
struct BstNode{
    string nameValue; // Names
    vector<int> pseudoIDS; // Unique IDs
    BstNode* left;
    BstNode* right;
};
```

I want to search vector for IDs. Im getting wrong bool returns now - I guess the search is wrong.

```
bool Search(BstNode* root, int data, vector<int>& ids){
int i = 0; // vector position
do{
   if(root == NULL){
     return false;
}
else if (root->pseudoIDS[i] == data){
    return true;
}
else if (data <= root->pseudoIDS[i]) {
     return Search(root->left, data);
}
else
     return Search(root->right, data);
   i++;
   }while(i == ids.size())

}
```

**_____ ALL CODE____**

Right now when I look for ID, if the search by ID gives positive result, it returns first node, even if the ID selected for the search should've given third node (for instance)

```
 struct BstNode{
 string nameValue; // Names
 vector<int> pseudoIDS; // Unique IDs
 BstNode* left;
 BstNode* right;
 };

 BstNode* GetNewNode(string name, vector<int>& ids){
 BstNode* newNode = new BstNode();
 newNode->nameValue = name;
 newNode->pseudoIDS.insert(newNode->pseudoIDS.end(), ids.begin(), ids.end()); // Inserting ids i     nto Node
 newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;
 return newNode;
 }

 BstNode* Insert(BstNode* root, string name, vector<int>& ids){
 // Tree is empty
 if (root == NULL) {
 root = GetNewNode(name, ids);
 return root;
 }
 else if(name <= root->nameValue){
 root->left = Insert(root->left, name, ids);
 }     
 else{
 root->right = Insert(root->right, name, ids);
 }
 return root;
 }

 void PrintTree (BstNode* node){
 if (node == NULL){ return; }
 PrintTree(node->left);

 cout << "Node string: " << node->nameValue << endl;
 PrintTree(node->right);
 }

 bool search(BstNode* root, int data)
 {
 if(root == NULL || root->pseudoIDS.size() == 0) return false;
 // we need a max and min counter to see where the element may lie if its not in this root node
 int max = root->pseudoIDS[0];
 int min = root->pseudoIDS[0];

 for(unsigned int i = 0; i < root->pseudoIDS.size(); i++) {
 if(root->pseudoIDS[i] == data) return true;
 // update max and min
 if(root->pseudoIDS[i] > max) max = root->pseudoIDS[i];
 if(root->pseudoIDS[i] < min) min = root->pseudoIDS[i];
 }

 if(data > max) return search(root->right, data); // if the element we are looking for is greater than max,      we search the right node
 else if(data < min) return search(root->left, data); // if the element is less than the min, we search the left
 else return false; // the element had to be in this vector if it existed
 }

 int main(){
 BstNode* root = NULL; // Creating empty BST


 // TEST
 vector<int> test;
 vector<int> test2;
 vector<int> test3;

 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ test.push_back(i); }
 for (int i = 10; i < 12; i++){ test2.push_back(i); }
 for (int i = 56; i < 60; i++){ test3.push_back(i); }

 root = Insert(root, "Abuels", test);
 root = Insert(root, "Caves", test2);
 root = Insert(root, "Zapes", test3);
 root = Insert (root, "Bib", test);

 // Print
 PrintTree(root);

 cout << "Searching by ID: " << endl;

 if(search(root, 11) == 1){
 cout << root->nameValue;
 }
 else
 cout << "nope";


 return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Are you trying to search the `psuedoIDS` vector for that particular `data` value?

Comment: The way this BST/search method is set up I find somewhat odd. There is pretty much no point in you looping because your function recursively jumps on the first element of the root node because of the way the if statements are set up. I believe you want to loop through the root vector first, then determine if you need to recursive the left or right node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off my comment heres a solution. I assumed that your IDs vector is not sorted (if it *is* sorted then you can optimize it much more). This differs from your solution because it checks the root node's vector first and then it decides whether the element lies in the right node, left node, or neither. I also assumed that your BST is set up as follows: the left node has values lower than root, and the right node has values higher than root. If you did this the other way around, you only have to make some small changes.

```
bool search(BstNode* root, int data)
{
    if(root == NULL || root->values.size() == 0) return false;
    // we need a max and min counter to see where the element may lie if its not in this root node
    int max = root->values[0];
    int min = root->values[0];

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < root->values.size(); i++) {
        if(root->values[i] == data) return true;
        // update max and min
        if(root->values[i] > max) max = root->values[i];
        if(root->values[i] < min) min = root->values[i];
    }

    if(data > max) return search(root->right, data); // if the element we are looking for is greater than max, we search the right node
    else if(data < min) return search(root->left, data); // if the element is less than the min, we search the left
    else return false; // the element had to be in this vector if it existed
}

int main()
{
    // initalizing the structures:
    BstNode left = {"Left", std::vector<int>(), NULL, NULL};
    BstNode right = {"Right", std::vector<int>(), NULL, NULL};
    BstNode root = {"Root", std::vector<int>(), &left, &right};

    // left has values lower than root
    // right has values higher than root
    // slightly randomized to show it still works
    left.values.push_back(0);
    left.values.push_back(2);
    left.values.push_back(1);
    root.values.push_back(4);
    root.values.push_back(2);
    root.values.push_back(3);
    right.values.push_back(5);
    right.values.push_back(7);
    right.values.push_back(6);

    std::cout<< search(&root, 0) << std::endl; // left node test case; should return true
    std::cout<< search(&root, 8) << std::endl; // impossible case; should return false
    std::cout << search(&root, 7) << std::endl; // right node test case; should return true
    std::cout << search(&root, 3) << std::endl; // root node test case; should return true

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: to answer the second question:

From your testing main method, this is incorrect:

```
if(search(root, 11) == 1){
cout << root->nameValue; // this will _always_ print the root node's name
}
else
cout << "nope";
```

I am guessing you want to print the name of node in which the value lies. To solve this, you could create another function called find which does the same thing, but it returns a pointer to the node.

For example:

```
BstNode* find(BstNode* root, int data)
{
    if(root == NULL || root->values.size() == 0) return NULL;
    // we need a max and min counter to see where the element may lie if its not in this root node
    int max = root->values[0];
    int min = root->values[0];

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < root->values.size(); i++) {
        if(root->values[i] == data) return root;
        // update max and min
        if(root->values[i] > max) max = root->values[i];
        if(root->values[i] < min) min = root->values[i];
    }

    if(data > max) return find(root->right, data); // if the element we are looking for is greater than max, we search the right node
    else if(data < min) return find(root->left, data); // if the element is less than the min, we search the left
    else return NULL; // the element had to be in this vector if it existed
}
```

This returns a *pointer* to the node which contains what you are looking for. So you would do this in your test:

```
BstNode* ptr = find(root, 11);
if(ptr != NULL){
 cout << ptr->nameValue;
}
else
cout << "nope";
```

Comment: That worked! Kinda... When I tried to find a root->nameValue by ID, it always gives me first node, even tho if the ID is from the third node. What could cause this? I edited original post with whole code.

Comment: @KaskyWoo, thats because your search method returns a _boolean_. It returns true if the node is in _any_ of the root node's children (mean all the children of the root and the root itself). Look at my edit.

Comment: It says now, that it can't convert bool to BstNode in return "else if(data < min) return search(root->left, data); "

Comment: Oh sorry I made a typo. Please look at the code again. I should have been recursively calling "find" in the find function, not calling search.